# My vba has stopped working again?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This time I was making option boxes so I put in the code with the speech marks around the answer then I tried using it but it just wouldn't work. The code I put in was:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    If OptionButton1.Value = "Stores all the components" Then
        MsgBox "That is correct. Well done!"
        SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry, that is not right. Try again"
    End If
End Sub
```

Please can someone help me?

Comment: If I remember correctly (and assuming `OptionButton1` is an OptionButton instance), the `Value` property is a Boolean and not String.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say please explain it further

Comment: See Siddharth's answer. I think he's on the right track.

Comment: I have given you the code for checking the caption but I think you actually want to check if the value is true or not...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying this

```
If OptionButton1.Caption = "Stores all the components"
```

or This

```
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
```

Comment: So what do I need to put in

Comment: I feel it should be the 2nd one that you need because how many captions can one option button have ;)

Comment: I put it in but it still doesn't work like when I click on the answer I want it says wrong try again when I click on the other ones nothing happens

Comment: I just tried the 2nd code and it worked both in Userform and in the Slide :)

Answer (score 0):

An optionButton in VBA has a Value of 0 (unchecked) or -1 (checked).  If you are looking for what the optionbutton says, I believe you want .Caption instead of .Value

EDIT:
After looking at your code again, I see a fundamental flaw.  You are assigning this to just option click, so if the first button does not have the correct value, then nothing will happen.  I think what you need is a subroutine like this

```
Private Sub checkAnswer (answer as string)
    dim expecTedAnswer as string
    expectedAnswer = "The correct answer"
    if answer = expectedanswer then
        msgbox "Correct"
    else
        msgbox "Incorrect"
    end if
End sub
```

Then in the option click, just call the Sub

```
CheckAnswer(OptionButton1.Caption)
```

Note that this is extremely ugly (you would want to create an easily usable calling method and way of setting the correctAnswer), but it should give you something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

A little prettier perhaps ...

Each OptionButton click event calls CheckAnswer:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    If CheckAnswer(Me.OptionButton1, "Correct answer") Then
        MsgBox "Good user.  GOOD!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Bad user!  BAD!  Go stand in the corner."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    If CheckAnswer(Me.OptionButton2, "Correct answer") Then
        MsgBox "Good user.  GOOD!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Bad user!  BAD!  Go stand in the corner."
    End If
End Sub

Function CheckAnswer(oCtl As Object, sCorrectAnswer As String) As Boolean
    If UCase(oCtl.Caption) = UCase(sCorrectAnswer) Then
        CheckAnswer = True
    Else
        CheckAnswer = False
    End If
End Function
```